# How to add more than 6 segments with image on iphone using uisegmentcontrol

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

The thing is i can add segments as much as i want if i use text but if i use image means i can not able to add more than 6 segments on iphone.

help me out.

```
    UIImage* resetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Reset_V1"];
    UIImage* wlwwImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Reset_V1"];
    UIImage* huImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HU_PI_V1"];
    UIImage* panImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Panning_V1"];
    UIImage* disImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Distance_V1"];
    UIImage* areaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Reset_V1"];
    UIImage* clrImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Clear_V1"];
    UIImage* presetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Presets_V1"];

        mySegments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: wlwwImage,panImage,huImage,disImage,areaImage,resetImage,clrImage,presetImage, nil];
   segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:mySegments];
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 35);
    segmentControl.frame = myFrame;
    [segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(whichSegment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentControl];
```

Comment: Hi, I submit answer and with demo project is that help or still need more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I try with same code and it work**
**Output:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
    UIImage* resetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* wlwwImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* huImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* panImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* disImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* areaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* clrImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* presetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* presetImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* presetImage2= [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* presetImage3= [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];

    NSArray *mySegments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: wlwwImage,panImage,huImage,disImage,areaImage,resetImage,clrImage,presetImage,presetImage1,presetImage2,presetImage3, nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:mySegments];
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 35);
    segmentControl.frame = myFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:segmentControl];
```

**Download demo project**
[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbajjtg0k6tw9os/demoSegment.zip?dl=0)

---

**If your image path is not valid then it will show only segment with correct image**

[image]

**Code(with bug)**

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage* resetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* wlwwImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* huImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* panImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* disImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
    UIImage* areaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"]; // wrong image name
    UIImage* clrImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"]; // wrong image name
    UIImage* presetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"]; // wrong image name
    UIImage* presetImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"]; // wrong image name
    UIImage* presetImage2= [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"]; // wrong image name
    UIImage* presetImage3= [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"]; // wrong image name

    NSArray *mySegments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: wlwwImage,panImage,huImage,disImage,areaImage,resetImage,clrImage,presetImage,presetImage1,presetImage2,presetImage3, nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:mySegments];
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 35);
    segmentControl.frame = myFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:segmentControl];
```